# How to replace xmlNode from another node

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have two xml files and both files contain an element node say "MarketData".

What I want to is replace the MarketData node from second file to first file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my question. Here is for others references...

```
OldNode.ReplaceWith(secondDocument.Element("MarketData"));
```

OldNode is XElement and secondDocument is second xml file from where we want new Node.

Thanks